# Calculating TP, FP, TN, FN values

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to build a very simple program for calculating TP/FP/FN/TN for 2 strings (predicted secondary protein structure vs proven secondary protein structure), but it does not calculating them correctly.  What is it that I am missing?

```
actual_str = '*ΟΟΟΟΟΟ******////////////**//////////*****////ΟΟΟΟΟΟΟΟΟ***'
predicted_str = '****--********/////////-----//////****----**-ΟΟΟΟΟΟΟ/-****'

TP = 0
FP = 0
TN = 0
FN = 0

for i in range(len(predicted_str)): 
    if predicted_str[i]==actual_str[i]=='O':
        TP += 1
        
    if predicted_str[i]!='O' and actual_str[i]=='O': 
        FP += 1
        
    if predicted_str[i]==actual_str[i]=='/' or predicted_str[i]==actual_str[i]=='*':
        TN += 1
        
    if predicted_str[i]=='O' and actual_str[i]!='O':
        FN += 1
        
    if predicted_str[i]=='-': #just ignore the '-' and move on to the next
        i+=1

print(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

Output: 0 0 26 0

Comment: I think the problem is with using the == operation twice in a row instead of doing 
if predicted_str[i]==actual_str[i] and actual_str[i]=='O':
and in the other places.
If I'm not mistaken, what that does if compare the boolean output of the first comparison to the third item. and True does not equal 'O'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange one, but try to copy one of the 'O' character used in the `actual_str` or `predicted_str` variables, and paste that in your if-statements. I think there is a mismatch, even though they look identical.

Also the last if-statement is not necessary.

Comment: Yep, the characters of the if statement is different:
You have the O capital letter and the Ο omicron greek letter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still don't see any difference tbh but that was it!

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, the characters you are using are different, it mixes the greek letter O omicron and the Latin o capital.

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%CE%9F

In addition instead of compare it by index, it make sense to use a zip operator in this usecase:

```
for (actual, predicted) in zip(actual_str, predicted_str):
   if (..
```

Comment: Thanks. I really wouldn't have noticed, must have forgotten to switch languages. I will try this as well.